# Multiple promises in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am new to nodejs and struggling to find the issue with the below piece of code.

All i am trying to achieve is, calling few methods one after other and if all the calls are successful, then return success else throw an error if any of the method fails.

Issue i have is, before all the method gets executed, the main method terminates even though the promises are yet to be fullfilled.

Main method

```
processRequest(neworder).then(function (done) {
    console.log('Successfully processed the order' + done);
    res.sendStatus(200);
}).fail(function (error) {
    res.status(404).send(error);
})
```

Other method calls

```
module.exports.processRequest = function (Order) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    findX(Order)
        .then(findYBasedOnPrevOutput)
        .then(findZBasedOnPrevOutput)
        .then(deferred.resolve())
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log('Failed to process request' + err);
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}


var findX = function (order) {
    var deferred = Q.defer()

    db.list(order, function (address) {
        console.log('Query success');
        if (address == null)
            deferred.reject('Error');
        else {
            deferred.resolve(address);
        }
    })

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Issue that i am having is, i see in the console the success just after the findX method gets called. I expected the success msg after findZ method.

Can you please help me in finding the issue with the above code, appreciate your input/suggestions in this regard

For simplicity, i didn't share the other modules here, but they are very similar to findX

Comment: `    .then(deferred.resolve())` should be `    .then(() => deferred.resolve())` - what you're doing is like `setTimeout(fn(), 100)` instead of `setTimeout(fn, 100)`. Also, you're doing explicit construction: stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum.. Thanks it helped. Changing the .then(deferred.resolve()) to .then(deferred.resolve) fixed the issue...And thanks for sharing the wonderful link.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Can you post your response as answer, so that i can accept.

Comment: No, you should probably delete your quesiton as it's a typo issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you just use the promise you already have rather than creating a new one as both more efficient and to avoid a promise anti-pattern:

```
module.exports.processRequest = function (Order) {
  return findX(Order)
    .then(findYBasedOnPrevOutput)
    .then(findZBasedOnPrevOutput)
    .fail(function (err) {
      // log the error, then throw it again so it is returned as a rejected promise
      console.log('Failed to process request' + err);
      throw(err);
    });
}
```

And, I'd suggest changing `findX` to use Q's ability to turn a standard async call into one that returns a promise like this:

```
var findX = function(order) {
  return Q.nfcall(db.list.bind(db), order);
};
```

---

Or, combine the two like this:

```
module.exports.processRequest = function (Order) {
  return Q.nfcall(db.list.bind(db), Order)
    .then(findYBasedOnPrevOutput)
    .then(findZBasedOnPrevOutput)
    .fail(function (err) {
      // log the error, the throw it again so it is returned as a rejected promise
      console.log('Failed to process request' + err);
      throw(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, was googling to understand more on the nfcall, looks to me, its a handy method to wrap around all the legacy callback methods. But given all my methods are new, wondering will that be worth spending another day to get them changed to return the promise as explained in the 1st response, or should i just wrap them with nfcall. Which is the best way, any suggestion over there.. Again thanks for taking time to respond..

Comment: @Shiv - Once you get comfortable with promises, you will find that you pretty much want to use them for ALL your async operations as they offer significant advantages in coordinating multiple async operations and in error handling and in code readability.  So, I'd suggest you "promisify" all the async functions you use.  I use [Bluebird's `.promisifyAll()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) which will promisify the entire interface from a module in one line of code.

Comment: @Shiv - It's generally best to promisify things once at the beginning of a module so that overhead is done and you can then just program with promises, but if there's a one-off async function, you can certainly use `Q.nfcall()` with it as needed.